# How to merge but also split a careted button? (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, caret

Unfortunately the title I have given is very vague. I honestly wasn't sure how to word it. Anyway, basically I currently have a vertical navbar with a small caret beside the text. Once clicked, the particular button uncollapses and shows it's contents.

[image]

As seen in the image above, I'm attempting to have a secondary caret that should be sitting on the right of the button. This caret will follow suit on every other button once I get it working. Anyway, I'm currently using twitter-bootstrap and from what I understand, I could be able to split the button into 2, each having their own function. For example, if one were to click the text and the downwards caret, it should uncollapse the menu (Which it does fine right now). Though, when you click the right facing caret, it should just bring you to another page via an href or something. Currently, clicking either button will collapse and uncollapse the menu.

As you can see, the right facing caret separates itself from the original button but in a weird way. On the far right of the image is an example of the button separation I would like. In the Twitter-Bootstrap example, the "button" text and the caret both do different functions. I'm not entirely sure on how to achieve this via the current button setup I have. I'm quite happy with how the current buttons look visually but I want to be able to add that secondary caret that is justified to the right of the button. As well as have that secondary button separate nicely, similar to that of the Twitter-Bootstrap example.

**TL;DR**: how do I get a button to split into 2 piece via the current HTML that I have. I would like to keep the styling and I would like each button to have it's own functionality.

(Enlarge image)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANPWm.png

Comment: I had the image there linked to an imgur so that one could zoom in but for some reason that disappeared. I will add it again at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make two buttons and style them to be close to one another. Use CSS styling to get it done. You can lower the margins on the sides to get them closer, you could use border-radius to get rid of the corners in the middle, etc etc.

Just figure out how you want it to look. And forget about splitting buttons, that is not something you can technically do, or should want. Create 2 buttons and style them.

Comment: Twitter-Bootstrap already has the functionality to do it though. At least, in the image example in the far right. Though, that method doesn't seem to work properly. I'm not sure how to go about the method you're suggesting.

Comment: That looks like <select><option>~<option><option>~<option><select>